# Trying a Java pong

Tags: java, swing, awt, keypress, paintcomponent

I'm trying to do a Java Pong game. I have very little experience with Java and need some help. I've read a lot of stuff online, and below is the code I've come up with.
I've created the following classes, but all I get is a grey screen. I'm just trying to implement the simplest solution for this. Could anyone point out any issues this code has? Thank you.

```
    package pong_test_1;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    /**
     *
     * @author jtrinidad
     */

    public class main_class extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
        static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
        static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
        JFrame f;

        public main_class()
        {
            super();
            addKeyListener (this);
            setFocusable (true);

            f = new JFrame("Pong");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            f.setResizable(false);

            f.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
            f.setVisible(true);

        }

        @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            Pong_Test_1 p = new Pong_Test_1();
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            switch( keyCode ) { 
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    Pong_Test_1.p2_pos_y--; 
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    Pong_Test_1.p2_pos_y++; 
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_Q:
                    Pong_Test_1.p1_pos_y++; 
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_A :
                    Pong_Test_1.p1_pos_y++; 
                    break;
            }
            add(p);
            repaint();
        }

        /** Handle the key released event from the text field. */
         @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

         public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
             main_class c = new main_class();
        }


    }
```

and

```
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package pong_test_1;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;



    /**
     *
     * @author jtrinidad
     */
    public class Pong_Test_1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        //Sizes of each object
        static final int WIDTH = 10;
        static final int HEIGHT = 120;
        static final int RADIUS = 10;
        //Position of Player 1's paddle
        static int p1_pos_x = 10;
        static int p1_pos_y = main_class.FRAME_HEIGHT/2;
        //Position of Player 2's paddle
        static int p2_pos_x = main_class.FRAME_WIDTH - 20;
        static int p2_pos_y = main_class.FRAME_HEIGHT/2;;
        //Position of the ball
        static int ball_pos_x;
        static int ball_pos_y;


        Timer animator;

        public Pong_Test_1()
        {
            animator = new Timer (10, this);
            animator.start();
        }


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK); //Sets background color

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(p1_pos_x, p1_pos_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            g.fillRect(p2_pos_x, p2_pos_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            g.fillOval(100, 100, RADIUS, RADIUS);
        }

        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            repaint();
            revalidate();  // new line
        }

        private void addKeyListener(Pong_Test_1 aThis) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Start from the basics. Do you know how to color the screen at all? Here at SO you can ask specific questions but inspecting the entire source is not our job.

Comment: Also, you should follow naming conventions; no underscores in class/method names, and capitalize the first letter of each word for class names.

Comment: Calling `repaint();` in your `actionPerformed()` method is not calling `paintComponent()` like you think that it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) works more to your expectations, the main problem was both extending and having an instance of a `JFrame`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class main_class implements KeyListener {

    static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    JFrame f;

    public main_class() {
        f = new JFrame("Pong");

        JPanel gui = new JPanel();
        gui.setFocusable(true);
        gui.addKeyListener(this);
        f.setContentPane(gui);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setResizable(false);

        f.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // this will steal the focus for KeyEvents, or rather..
        // Pong_Test_1 p = new Pong_Test_1();
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(e);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                Pong_Test_1.p2_pos_y--;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                Pong_Test_1.p2_pos_y++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_Q:
                Pong_Test_1.p1_pos_y++;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                Pong_Test_1.p1_pos_y++;
                break;
        }
        // ..adding it will steal the content area & focus
        //add(p);
        f.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Handle the key released event from the text field.
     */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        main_class c = new main_class();
    }
}
```

As general advice:

- Don't extend frame, simply keep a reference to one.
- For Swing, use Key Bindings rather than a `KeyListener`.

Comment: But you don't have any drawing in your example.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov  The question is *"Could anyone point out any issues this code has?"*  That (above) is one.  Note also the comment starting with `// this will steal the focus for KeyEvents, or rather..`.  SO is not a 'one-top shop' for code fixes - BNI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There were many other stuff I had to modify, but the end product works great!

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't name your Class `main_class`, use `MainClass` or `PongWindow` instead -> [Java JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)
2. Your `main_class extends JFrame`, so this should be the JFrame to instantiate, don't create a new one in your constructor.
3. Create getter and setter for your fields in `Pong_Test_1`.
4. Read some more tutorials about OOP and Java at all.

---

```
private final Pong_Test_1 myPong;    

public PongWindow() {
  super();
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.addKeyListener(this);
  this.setFocusable(true);
  this.setResizable(false);
  this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);

  myPong = new Pong_Test_1();
  this.getContentPane().add(myPong);

  this.setVisible(true);
}
```

And in your `keyPressed()` Method use your instance to manipulate.

```
myPong.p2_pos_y--;
```

Comment: He adds instance of `Pong_test_1` to frame on key press so your `3. Your Component to paint on is your JPanel, but you don't put it in your window.` is wrong.

Comment: *"Your main_class extends JFrame, so this should be the Class you have to instantiate"*  The `main_class` does not need to extend frame.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov THX for that hint, changed my post

Comment: @AndrewThompson But it would be quite possible.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sure, this is not optimal. And I agree with you entirely. Composition is preferred over inheritance. But my code was a quick draft and I didn't want to change too much from the existing code. ;-)

Comment: *"didn't want to change too much from the existing code"*  OK - on that note, I see your point.  It is always hard to know when to stop.  looking over the code I posted I keep seeing other things that make me wince.  ;)